# Access next route information inside canDeactivate guard in new angular2 router

Tags: angular, router

How can i access the next route information inside "canDeactivate" guard in the angular2 new router

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck on that exact same problem. In my case, my canDeactivate logic will cancel/redirect the next route conditionally. At this point, hopefully there is a better way, I am using the following solution

1. From my component, hook into the `Router` events (specifically `RoutesRecognized`) to record the route for later use.
2. Implement the `canDeactivate` and use the saved route data to return true or false.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.tabbedSearch = this.profilesService.currentProfile.tabbedSearch;

 this.router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
  .map(e => <RoutesRecognized> e)
  .subscribe((e) => {
   this.lastRoute = e.state.root.firstChild.routeConfig.path;
   this.lastParams = e.state.root.firstChild.params;
  });
}

public canDeactivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
 // do not navigate away if we are doing tabbed search AND the new route is the article details view
 if (this.tabbedSearch && this.lastRoute == "article/details/:type/:id/:version") {
  this.tabbedDetails.push(Object.create(this.lastParams));

  return false;
 }
 else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

(Note: You **cannot** run the snippet but for some reason the Code Sample formatting was not rendering properly.)

I really, really do not like this but have not found any other way.